# Details of output of git remote -v

Tags: git, ssh

When I send command `git remote -v`

Like following result was returned.

```
backup  ssh://git.test.com:2222/product/sample/backup/user (fetch)
backup  ssh://git.test.com:2222/product/Sample/backup/user (push)
origin  ssh://git.test.com:2222/product/Sample (fetch)
origin  ssh://git.test.com:2222/product/Sample (push)
share   ssh://git.test.com:2222/product/Sample/share/user (fetch)
share   ssh://git.test.com:2222/product/Sample/share/user (push)
```

- What is the difference between backup, origin, share ?
- Why the url starts with ssh ? how to see repository in console ?

Comment: Who created the backup and share remotes? These names are arbitrary and not from git (at least, afaik), so there is no 'git' answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those URLS come from your local git configuration:

```
cd /path/to/repo
git config -local -l
```

You can add as many remote URL as you want with [`git remote set-url --add origin ...`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emset-urlem), either with HTTPS or SSH.

While `origin` generally references the original remote repository you have cloned, `backup` and `share` are only meaningful for the one who has added them.

I would guess in this case:

- `origin`: original repository, read-only (you cannot push back)
- `backup`: personal backup for that repository, in the user namespace of the remote Git repository hosting server
- `shared`: shared remote repository, accessed by other users, where you modification are visible (by other contributors)